# Carga de imagenes con CLOUDINARY y React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

tengo un problema al subir una imagen utilizando la API de Cloudinary desde mi Front. El error que se muestra en consola es el siguiente:

[image: error al momento de subir la imagen por el lado del Front]

ahora le muestro el codigo UploaderPage.jsx:

```js
const uploadFile = async (type) =>{
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", type === "file")
        data.append("upload_preset", "default-preset")

        try {
            let cloudName =CLOUDNAME;
            //let resourceType = type === "image" ? "image" : "file not";
            const api = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/image/upload`;

            const res = await axios.post(api,data);
            console.log(res)
            const {secure_url} = res.data;
            console.log(secure_url)
            return secure_url
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const imgUrl = await uploadFile("image");
            const re = await uploadRequest({imgUrl})
            setImg(null);
            console.log(re);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

codigo del controlador upload.controller.js:

```js
export const uploadImage = async(req,res) =>{
    const {name,type,description,date} = req.body

    try {
        const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
        const newImage = new Image({url:result.secure_url, name,type,description,date,user:req.user.id});
        const ImageSaved = await newImage.save();
        res.json({
            id:ImageSaved._id,
            name:ImageSaved.name,
            type:ImageSaved.type,
            description:ImageSaved.description,
            date:ImageSaved.date,
            url:ImageSaved.url,
            createdAt:ImageSaved.createdAt,
            updateAt:ImageSaved.updatedAt
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Cabe mencionar que haciendo las pruebas desde el Backend con postman, no ocurre ningún error funciona correctamente

Comment: Verifica que esto `req.file.path` este legando antes del try en `uploadImage `

Comment: me devuelve un undefined

Comment: entonces el parámetro `path` no existe en la estructura `req.file`por lo tanto cuando lo envías tienes `Cannot read properties of undefined:path`, lanza un console a `req.file` para ver que hay ahi dentro.